# too many 404 error with url " index.php? " found in google search console

Tags: laravel, indexing, google-search-console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/javwl.jpg)

by the way CRM of this site is php

Remove 404 errors named index.php?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFHWL.jpg)

Comment: Are those just from google crawlers? or are those general 404 errors your site reported?

Comment: google crawler. 
 something generate a lot of 404 error pages.

Comment: Is there a way to determine where the crawler found those links? The google cralwer will generally start at the entry points you specify and visit links as deep as it can

Comment: I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to find their source and fix or remove them accordingly. You can find that source when you select a URL and then click on **Inspect URL**.

[image]

On the newly appeared page opposite the **Referring page**, you will see where Googlebot found this link.

[image]

Comment: I've removed this urls but site generate new 404 errors everyday.

Comment: Surely it;s referred to index.php files or some problems site map

Comment: Remove this declaration from the source code so it won't appear in the frontend, therefore crawlers won't collect these links.